# Как получить адрес смещения или указатель на метод интерфейса в Delphi

Tags: delphi, указатели, интерфейс, code-injection, direct3d

У меня есть указатель на интерфейс IDirect3DDevice9, в котором 119 методов (включая 3 стандартных), реализованных в d3d9.dll.

**Мне нужно получить в моем Delphi коде смещения (в байтах) на методы интерфейса EndScene() и Present() относительно начала библиотеки (указатель на DLL).**

```
var:
    g_pD3DDevice: IDirect3DDevice9;
    ProcAddr: Pointer;
    hD3D9: HMODULE;
    Present9 : DWORD;
    EndScene9: DWORD;

implemenation:
    hD3D9 := LoadLibrary('d3d9');
    ProcAddr := GetProcAddress(hD3D9, 'Direct3DCreate9');
    ...
    pD3D.CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, TargetHandle, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, @D3DPP, g_pD3DDevice);
```

Предполагаю, что в VMT метод Present() стоит на 17-м месте (0-based), а EndScene() на 42-м, потому что так написано в заголовочном файле d3d9.dll.

Но мне не кажется хорошей идеей высчитывать смещение подобным образом:

```
Present9 := DWORD(g_pD3DDevice) + (17 * 4) - DWORD(hD3D9);
EndScene9 := DWORD(g_pD3DDevice) + (42 * 4) - DWORD(hD3D9);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста лучшее решение данной задачи!

Comment: Какой задачи? Что такое "начало библиотеки"?

Comment: зачем вам вообще какие то смещения при наличии интерфейса?

Comment: Точно не скажу, но через отладчик попробуйте поковыряться. Там есть вариант отладки кода с адресами...

Comment: В вопросе же написано: начало библиотеки (DLL pointer) — ProcAddr; смещения нужны потому что я хочу узнать адрес метода Present() экземпляра IDirect3DDevice9 уже ранее созданного в стороннем процессе. Наверное из описания вопроса понятно, что я делаю инжектор в сторонний процесс, для этого нужны смещения. Но у меня нет уверенности, что метод именно под номером 17 и что указатель длинной 4 байта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такое [решение найдено](http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/01/using-anonymous-methods-in-method.html) на просторах интернета.

Пример реализации такой:

1) Объявляю процедурный тип нужного метода

```
type
  TPresent9 = function(pSourceRect, pDestRect: PRect; hDestWindowOverride: HWND; pDirtyRegion: PRgnData): HResult of object; stdcall;
```

2) Объявляю переменную этого типа

```
var
  PPresent: TPresent9;
begin
  ...
  IntRefToMethPtr(d3d9Dev, PPresent, 17);
  PPresent(nil, nil, DParametrs.D3DPP.hDeviceWindow, nil);
```

3) Реализую процедуру получения метода интерфейса по номеру

```
procedure IntRefToMethPtr(const IntRef; var MethPtr; MethNo: Integer);
type
  TVtable  = array [0 .. 999] of Pointer;
  PVtable  = ^TVtable;
  PPVtable = ^PVtable;
begin
  // QI=0, AddRef=1, Release=2, etc
  TMethod(MethPtr).Code := PPVtable(IntRef)^^[MethNo];
  TMethod(MethPtr).Data := Pointer(IntRef);
end;
```

4) А теперь получаем метод интерфейса по его порядковому номеру и вызываем его

```
  IntRefToMethPtr(d3d9Dev, PPresent, 17);
  PPresent(nil, nil, DParametrs.D3DPP.hDeviceWindow, nil);
```

Comment: Вы ответили на вопрос _"Как вызвать метод интерфейса по его порядковому номеру"_. Но вопрос-то был задан не про это.

Comment: Смотрите 4) пункт. Получаю указатель на метод в параметр PPresent. А смещение получается простой операцией сложения PPresent - d3d9Dev.

Answer (score 1):

Переменная интерфейсного типа является указателем на `Interface Method Table (IMT)` - таблицу методов интерфейса, в которой находятся указатели на код соответствующих методов:

[image: vmt]

В Delphi есть специальная ассемблерная инструкция - `VMTOFFSET`, которая позволяет получить смещение в байтах адреса виртуального метода относительно начала таблицы виртуальных методов (VMT)

> VMTOFFSET retrieves the offset in bytes of the virtual method pointer
>   table entry of the virtual method argument from the beginning of the
>   virtual method table (VMT). This directive needs a fully specified
>   class name with a method name as a parameter (for example,
>   TExample.VirtualMethod), or an interface name and an interface method
>   name.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Assembler_Syntax

Таким образом, зная имя нужного нам метода, можно получить указатель на его код:

```
function GetPresentMethodPointer(const IntRef: IInterface): Pointer; assembler;
asm
  mov eax, [IntRef] 
  add eax, vmtoffset IDirect3DDevice9.Present
  mov eax, [eax]
end;

var
  VD3Dev: IDirect3DDevice9;
  VPresentCodePtr: Pointer;
begin
  ... 
  // создание экземпляра VD3Dev
  ...
  VPresentCodePtr := GetPresentMethodPointer(VD3Dev);
  ...
```

И не нужно высчитывать порядковые номера методов.

Comment: Пробую. А есть идеи, как применять для получения произвольного метода интерфейса?

Comment: @PaxBeach Нет, произвольный не получится.